# How to download complete Azure IAAS Environment Set Up for DR purposes

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have set up an Azure environment for MyWork which contains a Virtual Network, 7 Cloud Services, 3 Storage Accounts, Traffic Manager and more than 20 Virtual Machines making use of Availability Sets and Affinity Groups including configuration and lockdown on the endpoints.

This was mostly created using the Portal during a workshop of various SME's but also makes use of Set-AzureACLConfig on the endpoints

I am required to create and document for DR purposes a method of re-creating the set up.

Does anyone know of a method of auto-generating the Powershell scripts to re-create the environment or do I have to go through and set up each with Powershell myself?

I have the skills to recreate each portion of the environment in Powershell but wondered if anyone else had solved this issue already.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution to your problem. You have to go through the whole setup, keep in mind dependencies and create the PowerShell yourself.

Comment: That is what I think the answer is, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure IaaS with PowerShell Quick Start Kit which was released end of October can be a good start. It has sample Powershell code to deploy several virtual machine, makes them part of availability sets and add to loadbalancer

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yungchou/archive/2013/10/30/announcing-windows-azure-iaas-quick-start-kit-qsk-at-http-aka-ms-qsk.aspx

Comment: Thank you but that script is for deploying environments. We had already created an environment using the gui and needed to create a powershell script for DR purposes